# Why is e.target.value undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is e.target.value undefined when logged to the console in this very simple component? The value is defined within the element so I don't understand why e.target returns the value as undefined.

```
const NavBar = () => {

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        console.log(e)
    }
    
    return (
        <div id="navbar">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/home" onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.target.value)}>Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" value={1} onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.target.value)} > About</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" value={2} onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.target.value)} > Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NavBar
```

Comment: [`a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes) elements don't have a `value` attribute

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) and [`e.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) use the latter to reference the element **you attached the event listener to:**

> It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to Event.target, which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant.

— MDN about `Event.currentTarget`

As other answers mention, use `data-*` attributes for custom attributes like:

```
<a href=".." data-value="value"></a>
```

And read it with:

```
e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-value")
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` elements don't have the `value` attribute. That why you get undefined.

Answer (score -2):

a tag doesn't have a value property

You can use `getAttribute`

```
e.target.getAttribute('value')
```

Although, you should use `data-value` and get it through `e.target.dataset.value`

Right now you are adding unexisting attributes

Comment: Or just use the element as it is intended in the spec

Comment: Yes, `data-value` would be better here

Comment: There's also an important difference between `e.target` and `e.currentTarget` most of the time you want the latter.